# WPF DataGrid updating cell style after editing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In XAML I have a column in a DataGrid that is defined like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource
               {x:Type DataGridCell}}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding
                    Converter={StaticResource NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The `NameToBrushConverter` returns a color when the `Name` column and the `FirstName` column have the same content. Otherwise it returns `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

The problem I'm facing is that if I edit a cell and end editing, the style is not updated. Only if the newly entered value moves to a different line (because of sorting) the conditional coloring of the background is applied. But if after editing the object is displayed in the same row of the `DataGrid` the background color get's not updated until I click on sort. As soon as the cell moves to a different row the background will be updated according to the Converter value.

Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the object doesn't help.

Is there a way to tell the `GridView` that it has to reevaluate the styling after editing a cell?

```
dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Calling refresh helps, but which is the right event to trigger a refresh? I tried it in `CellEditEnding`, but got an exception `Refresh` is not allowed in `AddNew-` or `EditItem` transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`  because it is by default set to `LostFocus` within a `DataGrid`.
2. I'm guessing that you do not have a `CellEditTemplate`.
3. **This is the biggest issue of all** : You would have to use multi-binding on your properties with a relevant Converter. The only reason this is working now is because when lost focus occurs the binding in the current cell refresh and gets your item **(i.e. binding or binding to `Path=`)**, passing it to the converter and outputting some color.

**Edit:**

I know see that I put the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the wrong binding.
Place it on the Name above and in your cell style also bind to `Name`.

**XAML:**

```
 <DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Name,
                            Converter={StaticResource
                            NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Further more, as for your question below. The only reason it was working in partially when moving between rows is because of the default UpdateSourceTrigger for every binding nested in a `DataGrid`, which is `LostFocus`.

When Binding to the current `DataContext` using :

```
<SomeElement Tag={Binding}/>
```

Or:

```
<SomeElement Tag={Binding Path=.}/>
```

You are not binding to a property. The Binding is evaluated when  :

1. The `DependencyObject` initializes and all it's DP's are evaluated. It gets it's value for the first time.
2. `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` (The default inside the `DataGrid`) it is eventuated on `LostFocus`. This is why your Binding is evaluated when you pass between rows.
3. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. If you want it on your `DataContext` you would have to explicitly set a property which would return itself and call it when the name property changes.

Something like this :

**C#:**

```
public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Self"));
        }
    }
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Self"));
        }
    }
    public Entity Self { get { return this; } }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged =
        delegate { };
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource
       {x:Type DataGridCell}}" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding
            Self,Converter={StaticResource NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

But this won't evaluate on `LostFocus`, but you wouldn't need it to any ways since it will evaluate the first time and then on any changes to name.

Comment: You example is working, but I have one more question.

Comment: I changed the converter that way that I get the object as parameter. So I write just <Binding /> instead of adding Path and Name and FirstName. So I get the whole object. As long as I add a second Binding Path with any property (eg <Binding Path="MyProperty" />, the field is updated. But when I only pass the object (only <Binding /> and remove all other bindings that contain a Path, the PropertyChangeEvent does not trigger the style update. Is there any way to make this work without passing 2 strings, but with passing a Person object?

Comment: What do you mean by passing the object itself. as i stated above for the binding of the object iteself ( i.e. Binding) it only happens the first time and on each LostFocus. You see you do not have a property to bind to which you raise a property changed event on.  I'm guessing you  could expose a property, something like Self { get return this;}  and raise a property changed event for it. but you'll have to  do that in your class when your Name of FirstName changes and that would be  much less readable then my solution.

Comment: The last thing is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: because you need the entity in the converter? 
i just think it's much less readable. you can't figure out when the binding is evaluated by looking at the xaml.