# How to change WPF DataGrid row color on double-click?

Tags: wpf

Please, can someone help me with this?
My code is the following:

```
 private void DGImageList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    object i = DGImageList.SelectedItem;
    //Set the selected row background colour to red
 }
```

Comment: The question is in the title. That is "how to change the background/foreground colour of a wpf datagrid row on mouse double click?"

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036580/wpf-change-datagrid-cell-row-background-color-dynamically-at-runtime/38041966#38041966), a sample of changing color on event

Comment: Thanks Celso. The suggested code works on DataGrid_LoadingRow event but i need it on mouse double click event.  I'm basically trying to get the following working: private void DGImageList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow gridRow = e.Row;
            DataRow row = (gridRow.DataContext as DataRowView).Row;
            gridRow.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }

Comment: your post has been edited, see if there is something waiting for approval, so that his code is more visible

Comment: I'm thinking about your question, the row color is already changed when you click on the grid, what do you really need? and what will happen if double click on another row?

Comment: Code has been approved now. Please can you have a look - thanks.

Comment: The Datagrid contains list of file paths that user double clicks on individual row to launch/open the files one at a time (have a code to do that). As they click through the files, I want the row's background colour change and remain changed. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here all you need:

```
private void DGImageList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var index = ((DataGrid)sender).SelectedIndex;// 
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)((DataGrid)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

references:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
```

Comment: You're genius Celso. Thanks you very much for your help. I'll sleep well tonight!

Comment: you are welcome, mark as answer, and have sweet dreams.:)